# Flow: Send email to those user who are in the group

Tags: visual-workflow, send-email

EDIT:
[image]

I'm creating a flow where the users in the Group will received an email via flow based on certain conditions:

I have done the following steps:

1. Configure start

[image]

2. "Get Records" from object "Group Member"

[image]

3. "Loop" through "Group Member" results

[image]

3.1 Use "Assignment" to add the user email address to the "Collection Variable"

[image]

3.3 (after last item) "Action" to send email and use the "Collection Variable" as Email Addresses (as long as the combined number of email addresses is five or fewer.)

[image]

Is there a way or workaround to send email individually to a user from a public group?

When I debug I see that

```
Result

{!User_Email} = "[]"
```

Comment: What is being added to `User_Email`? The title of that assignment seems to suggest you're adding an Id? Recipient Email Addresses expects actual email addresses that you would get from querying the user record using the UserOrGroupId from GroupMember.

Comment: i'm query the `Group` and for the `User_Email` I'm adding Email

Comment: this only works for one level Groups (what if you have groups that contain groups?) - Also - you are querying in `Get Records`  `Group` but you should be querying object `GroupMember`

Comment: changed it to `GroupMember` and in the `user_email` I'm adding `Group.Email` but still getting the empty, so what I'm trying to do is that, trying to send email to the users who are added to the `Group`

Answer (score 1):

So, you are going to need three Get Records elements

**Get Records 1**

- Query Group for `yourGroupName`

**Get Records 2**

- Query GroupMember where GroupId = result.Id from Get Records 1

**Loop**

- Build a collection variable of strings for each GroupMember where `UserOrGroupId` starts with `005` (meaning it is a User, not a Group)

**Get Records 3**

- Query User where ID = the collection variable built in the loop. This will yield 1 or more `User.Email` which is what you need.

---

Even if you used Apex, it would take two queries because the following isn't supported on `GroupMember` (no support for the `UserOrGroup` relationship as the schema describe doesn't expose that relationship)

```
SELECT Id, 
     TYPEOF UserOrGroup 
         WHEN User THEN Email 
     END 
   FROM GroupMember 
   WHERE UserOrGroup.Type = 'User' AND
         Group.Name = 'yourGroupName'
```

Comment: when query GroupMember, you only get `Id, GroupId, UserorGroupId`  I'm not sure where you going to define `Group.Name` in the GroupMember

Comment: It is a relationship (lookup) field

Comment: I edit my question and post the screen shot.

Comment: fixed - i forgot that you can't filter on relationship fields in Get Records - see this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdnoiUAB/flow-to-allow-cross-object-filters-in-lookups)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when you say `Build a collection variable of strings for each GroupMember....` what you mean by that do you mean create a loop? is that possible if you can put in a flow and have screen shots?